# Asp.net MVC Core - unable to load partial view using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Following this [article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/05/ajax-partial-views-asp-net-mvc.aspx), I'm tTrying to load `Partial View` via `Ajax`. But it's not loading `partial view`.

NOTES:

1. I'm using VS2015 with latest updates with default installation/configuration of Jquery that comes with Visual Studio's MVC Core web app project template.
2. Google Chrome's developer tool shows no error. And, the browser's view source still displays `<div id="UpdateTabData"></div>` tag empty
3. I've tested by placing `alert('Test')` inside the click event in the Ajax call and by using a `breakpoint` inside controller action method that Ajax is indeed calling the TestAction method and that the method is indeed returning `return PartialView("PartialView", myViemodel);` without any error inside action method.
4. But the Ajax at the end returns the my custom error message from it's error function

**Controller**:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TestAction(string calledFrom)
{
  ... some code here with a view model myViemodel

  return PartialView("myPartialViewName", myViemodel);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model myProj.Models.myTestViewModel
...some html here...
<div id="UpdateTabData"></div>
... more html here
...
```

**Ajax code at the end of view**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myTabstripID li').click(function () {
        var li_id = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("TestAction", "myControllerName")',
            data: { calledFrom: li_id},
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'html'
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#UpdateTabData').html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Error occurred');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Open your browser dev tools -> network tab and see the response of your ajax call. Is it 200 OK ? If not, check the response and see what you are getting. May be your server code is crashing

Comment: @Shyju yes, the `dev tools ->network->Headers` tab shows `status code: 200 OK`

Comment: What does the preview pane show in your dev tools?

Comment: @Shyju By using your comment I was able to resolve the issue by adding `.cshtml` extension in the `return PartialView("myPartialViewName", myViemodel);` statement in your controller. Sorry, I did not realize that the `status code: 200 OK` was in fact, after I found the message in response section that the view file was not found (my bad).  I had just casually added `.cshtml` extension and did not check that it, in fact, had resolved the issue. For the benefit of other users, if you convert your comment to an `answer` I would mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press f12 and check the URL to your action that should return the partial view.
2. Copy that URL and paste it to the browser address bar, press enter.
3. You will see the error (if there is an error) or your partial view.
4. If there is no error on step 3 try to type alert($('#UpdateTabData').length); in the console (should be 1 if you really have an element with such id);

This is very simple task (I mean to get some action result that returns an partial view), so it just should work. So it is possible that you just have wrong id or something minor like this somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove this part of your code.

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Based on your ActionResult in controller, you are returning a partial view. So your ajax call is expecting a view instead of json. This will fixed your problem.

Comment: This is false, content type defines the data type that you are sending, not receiving. DataType defines the content you are receiving.